# Creating self-signed SSL on IIS - Remote access problem

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate

I followed these instructions to [create self-signed SSL](http://www.visualwin.com/SelfSSL/) 
(I opened SelfSSL and typed `selfssl /T`).

When I access `https://localhost/` than it works, but when I try to access it remotely (i set up my router to port forward to `localhost`), for example `https://myip` the page does not load. Also, I noticed one other thing. When I access `localhost` locally then I am asked to enter user/pass, but if I access remotely the I get the following warning:

> Under Construction The site you were
>   trying to reach does not currently
>   have a default page. It may be in the
>   process of being upgraded and
>   configured. ...

I don't know if it is related with this but I hope someone know the answer.

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: What port are you forwarding in your router?

Comment: I am forwarding port 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things I see that may be wrong.

1. HTTPS uses port 443 not 80 or 8080, so if you are just specifying `https://myip` then it will try to access port 443, you either need to forward 443 or specify a port `https://myip:8080`.  If you go the 8080 route, you will need to be sure that IIS is listening for SSL connections on port 8080, not normal HTTP/port 80 traffic.
2. You said in your port forwarding rule you are forwarding to `localhost`.  Are you really forwarding to `localhost/127.0.0.1` or are you using your internal IP?  You need to make sure it is your internal IP address (likely `192.168.x.x`).

Comment: I am not currently by router so I draw settings - Are you suggesting that I should set it up like this: http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/2807/port.gif

Comment: Looks right, as long as you haven't changed the port that IIS is listening on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tommorow morning and let you know if it works

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works. Thanks once again!